PyMongo Authentication Failed With @ In Password
The following error happens when I'm trying to authenticate with an "@" in the password:
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Authentication failed.', 'code': 18, 'codeName': 'AuthenticationFailed'}
Here's the following code:
username = parse.quote_plus(db_info['username'])
password = parse.quote(db_info['password'])

ssh_server = SSHTunnelForwarder((ssh_info['ip'], ssh_info['port']), 
                                ssh_username=ssh_info['username'], 
                                ssh_password=ssh_info['password'],
                                remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 27017))
ssh_server.start()

test = pymongo.MongoClient('127.0.0.1', username=username, password=password)
db = test['DictatorBot']['ReactionRoles']
print(db.find_one())

The password is something along the lines of "p@ssw0rd" which is then turned to p%40ssw0rd" when using parse.quote/_plus.
I have to SSH Tunnel into the database before I can connect, not sure why it changed to where I need to when I didn't need to previously.
The Full Stack Trace/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A:\Discord Bots\Dictator Bot\test.py", line 50, in <module>
    print(db.find_one())
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1495, in find_one
    for result in cursor.limit(-1):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1243, in 
next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1160, in 
_refresh
    self.__send_message(q)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1039, in 
__send_message
    response = client._run_operation(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\_csot.py", line 108, in csot_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1425, in _run_operation
    return self._retryable_read(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1534, in _retryable_read
    return self._retry_internal(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\_csot.py", line 108, in csot_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1501, in _retry_internal
    ).run()
      ^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 2347, in run
    return self._read() if self._is_read else self._write()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 2479, in _read
    with self._client._conn_from_server(self._read_pref, self._server, self._session) as (
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1350, in _conn_from_server
    with self._checkout(server, session) as conn:
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1260, in _checkout
    with server.checkout(handler=err_handler) as conn:
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 1758, in checkout
    conn = self._get_conn(checkout_started_time, handler=handler)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 1916, in _get_conn
    conn = self.connect(handler=handler)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 1720, in connect
    conn.authenticate()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 1093, in authenticate
    auth.authenticate(creds, self, reauthenticate=reauthenticate)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 656, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, conn)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 560, in _authenticate_default
    return _authenticate_scram(credentials, conn, "SCRAM-SHA-1")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 299, in _authenticate_scram
    res = conn.command(source, cmd)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 327, in 
inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 985, in command
    return command(
           ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 212, in 
command
    helpers._check_command_response(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 233, in 
_check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(errmsg, code, response, max_wire_version)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Authentication failed.', 'code': 18, 'codeName': 'AuthenticationFailed'}

I have confirmed the username and password are correct as I am able to copy and paste the connection string into MongoDBCompass:
mongodb://us3rname:p@ssw0rd(or p%40ssw0rd)@127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&ssl=false&authSource=admin
I've tried adding "?directConnection=true&ssl=false&authSource=admin" to the end of the connection string with each setting removed/swapped out.

Does this answer your question? How to connect remote mongodb with pymongo

You only need to url-quote your username/password if you are connecting with a URI like mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/. When using SSH or the MongoClient() parameters, you should not url-quote your username or password. The APIs handle that. And wrt "I have to SSH Tunnel into the database before I can connect" - see  How to connect remote mongodb with pymongo - you need to specify the local_bind_port for MongoClient. Right now you're just connecting normally.

@aneroid, the first reply wasn't; it was more about the @ being within the password than remotely connecting with the SSH tunnel. Though I would like to correct this and do not need the SSH tunnel, it is not required and is my main focus. Those few changes made, were correct

@aneroid would you happen to know why I'm needing to suddenly SSH into the server before connecting to the DB now when I didn't beforehand?

That depends on what was changed. Maybe the DB has been moved to be behind a VPN/SSH tunnel, and previously it was only web accessible. However, I would expect that you should have a different username/password for SSH as well as a different cert. Having SSH with the same username & password as MongoDB defeats the purpose of the 'extra' security. At most, the IP address is different but that doesn't make it more secure. (You should send that feedback to your DevOps team or whoever manages your environments.)

@aneroid The DB and SSH are two different login information. The DB is run off of a rasp pi 5 ubuntu server 24.04 LTS within the same network, I was able to access it in CMD/terminal about two-ish days ago. This isn't an enterprise usage and more of a home usage as I'm making a discord bot (which will work outside of the bot but times out when I'm testing it on the bot which is very odd)

Okay, yeah, I see that it's a different variable.

Since more information was provided regarding the set up (everything ran locally, from the bot machine to dev machine to db machine all within the same network), you got any ideas on not being able to get into the db without shhing first?

@aneroid provided the answer
What he suggested was to change this line:
test = pymongo.MongoClient('127.0.0.1', username=username, password=password)
to
test = pymongo.MongoClient(host='127.0.0.1', port=ssh_server.local_bind_port, username=db_info['username'], password=db_info['password'])
This fixed the authentication issue failing when the username or password contained an "@" symbol.
